# django DeleteView - how to pass a parameter to use for success_url?

Tags: django, django-views

I am using a DeleteView where the I want to the success_url to be the view that called the DeleteView.  This success_url requires two parameters to be passed to it.

**model**

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, on_delete=CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('listparts/<uuid:company_pk>/<uuid:worker_pk>/', views.listparts, name='listparts'),
path('deletepart/<uuid:part_pk>/', views.PartDeleteView.as_view(), name='deletepart'),
```

**view**

```
def listparts(request, company_pk, worker_pk):
    ...
    ...

class PartDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Part
    success_url = reverse_lazy('listparts' company_pk worker_pk)
```

**listparts template**

```
<a href="{% url 'deletepart' part_pk %}">Delete this part</a>
```

**confirm_delete template**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}{{ form|crispy }}
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-2" value="Update">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

But I don't know how to deal with that in the `DeleteView`. I'm sure it has to do with dealing with `kwargs` but I'm still learning on how kwargs work in something like `def get_success_url(self)`

**Edit** I have included a model for `Part` and the template for the `confirm_delete`. From Willem Van Onsem's comment, I have modified the `PartDeleteView` to:

```
class PartDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Part

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('listparts', args={'company_pk':self.company.pk, 'worker_pk':self.worker.pk})
```

With this code, after I click the link to delete a part, I'm taken to the `confirm_delete` template.  Clicking the `Update` button doesn't do anything.  The page is taken to the success_url, and the part is not deleted.

Comment: What is your part object? Does it somehow has a `company_pk` and `worker_pk`?

Comment: Willem, yes. I've added code for the Part model. I also tried a new `PartDeleteView` view after reading your comments.  Edits are in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it makes more sense here to override the `get_success_url`, and thus implement this as:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class PartDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Part

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'listparts',
            kwargs={
                'company_pk': self.object.company_id
                'worker_pk': self.object.worker_id
            }
        )
```

Here `self.object` is the object that has been removed, and we thus access the `company_id` and `worker_id` of that object as `kwargs=…` for the URL we generate.